# "From the Sony company"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, grammaticality, difference, past-tense

> We have been received the certificate from the sony company.

Can we use **the company** in this sentence?

Comment: *We have been received* is improper. This is the passive construction and requires that the thing received be cast as Subject. Say either "We have received the certificate..." or "The certificate has been received...".

Answer (score 1):

Usually we would not use **the company**, because "Sony" is already a proper name and functions like a noun in that phrase, so you don't need another noun.  The normal versions would be

> ...from Sony.

if you want to use the name "Sony", or

> ...from the company.

if you don't want to state the name.

The only time you might use both the name and *the company* is when

- *the company* is actually part of the name, like

  > You will have to write to the Consolidated Mutual Company.

or

- you want to use *the company* in a phrase to clarify something about the name, like

  > This product is made by the Chinese company Pearl River.
  >   This company is made by the Heilongjiang company of China.

because your reader might not know that Pearl River or Heilongjiang are companies.